# Export environment variable from PHP CLI

Tags: php, bash, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a way to export an environment variable from a PHP script running with PHP CLI. The `putenv` function only permit to set variable that will be existing during script execution, not after.

My use case is a PHP script used as bash autocompleter function. In this type of function, we have to set *COMPREPLY* variable that must contain the list of available options (as a bash array). Currently, I'm setting this variable by this way :

```
COMPREPLY=( $(php myscript.php) )
```

I would like to have possibility to set *COMPREPLY* variable and some others (especially for action on default behavior on empty options list).

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't set an environment variable which survive the process. This is a basic property of the _environment_. However, the one you set using `putenv` is not only for the current process, but also for all subsequent child processes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer that I feared... ;) I will try to find another way to implement my needs.

Comment: You have several possibilities to communicate information as a string to the parent process, for instance writing it to stdout and have the parent intercept and interpret it, or write it to a file, which the parent process can read afterwards.